# How to test whether x is a member of a universal set?

Tags: python, math

I have a list L, and `x in L` evaluates to True if x is a member of L. What can I use instead of L in order `x in smth` will evaluate to True independently on the value of x?

So, I need something, what contains all objects, including itself, because x can also be this "smth".

Comment: what do you mean ? something like `x in [x]` ???

Comment: What's the use case for something like this? If x in L is always True, why can't you just replace x in L with True?

Comment: @Falmarri: suppose a container class provides a filtering interface that wants an object with `in` defined on it instead of a predicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class Universe:
    def __contains__(_,x): return True
```

Comment: Note that this creates the possibility of multiple universes, each containing all the others as elements. Set theory on steroids!

Comment: A set cannot contain all other sets. There is no universal set. You cannot, therefore, have multiple "universe" sets since you can't have a single universal set in the first place. This is basically a pythonic way of just answering `True` to the query - you have no rules for x belonging to universe - which is basically Falmarri's suggestion. -1.

Comment: @Ninefingers: this isn't seriously meant as a set theoretic construct, nor as a container. `Universe()` satisfies the OP's requirement of a `smth` to "use instead of `L` in order that `x in smth` will evaluate to `True` independently on the value of `x`."

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe I'm being a bit harsh. It does evaluate to true as required, I'll give you that. Python will actually let you implement a set that contains itself, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit from the built-in `list` class and redefine the `__contains__` method that is called when you do tests like `item in list`:

```
>>> class my_list(list):
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True


>>> L = my_list()
>>> L
[]
>>> x = 2
>>> x
2
>>> x in L
True
```

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem**: There is no universal set.

**Proof**. Let `X` be a set such that `X = {\empty, x}` where `x` is every possible element in the domain. The question arises, is `X \in X`? Most sets are not defined that way, so let us define a new set Y. `Y = {A \in X; A \notin A}` i.e. `Y` is the set of all sets not belonging to themselves.

Now, does `Y \in Y`? Well, we have defined Y as all sets not belonging to themselves, so Y cannot exist in Y, which contradicts our assumption.

So now assume Y is not in Y. Now A definitely contains Y, as Y is not in itself, but the definition of Y is such that if we define Y to be in Y, we contradict our own definition.

Thus, there is no set of all sets. This is known as [Russell's Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).

So, why programmatically try to create an object that violates a result proved and tested by set theorists far more intelligent than I am? If that was my interview, this would be my answer and if they insisted it was possible, I'd suggest explaining what the problem domain is, since conceptually Russell has fundamentally proved it is impossible.

If you want a user-friendly problem usually posed for people studying introductory set theory, try the [Barber Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox).

**Edit**: Python lets you implement an object that contains itself. See this:

```
class Universal(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.contents = []

    def add(self, x):
        self.contents.append(x)

    def remove(self, x):
        self.contents.remove(x)

    def __contains__(self, x):
        return ( x in self.contents )
```

However, this is not a strict set theoretic object, since  the contents actually contains a reference to the parent object. If you require that objects be distinct as per the proof above, this cannot happen.

Comment: In a computer program I can also prove that there are exist such primes, which are different from usual sequence {2,3,5,7,11,...}. Seriously, any set theory is just a product of the human nature, its perception and its physical environment. There are many set theories (non-naive, non-ZFC), which postulate existence of a Universal set.

Comment: Well, yes, it is fair to say that any such theorem is a result of the assumptions you make; namely that it depends on the axioms you have postulated. Prime is the name we give to irreducible quantities under our usual system of working, but it is quite acceptable to produce an entirely different set of axioms, which result in different "numbers" being irreducible. However, I'd say most people have a set of common assumptions. ZFC is what most people seem to go with; it is what is taught to undergrads.